Failure to initialize configuration for storage account: Invalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key
I'm executing a databricks job using the notebook task in Azure Data Factory. My data is landing successfully following a previously executed copy activity, however when I try to access this data in Databricks I am getting the following error:
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o393.load.
: Failure to initialize configuration for storage account $DATALAKENAME.dfs.core.windows.net: Invalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.keyInvalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.SimpleKeyProvider.getStorageAccountKey(SimpleKeyProvider.java:52)
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AbfsConfiguration.getStorageAccountKey(AbfsConfiguration.java:715)
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.initializeClient(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:2084)
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:272)
...

Setup steps:

I have defined a Storage Credential in Unity Catalog using the Databricks Access Connector.
I have defined an external location over the abfss:// filepath I am attempting to read data from.
I have granted my user account and the Data Factory MSI READ FILES and WRITE FILES permission on the external location
I have granted the Databricks Access Connector Storage Blob Data Contributor role on the storage account
I have granted the Data Factory Contributor role on the Databricks workspace

I am able to read the data when I run the notebook interactively under my user context, and am only receiving this error when I execute the notebook from ADF, so I know that I am able to successfully authenticate to storage using the access connector/external location. I do not want to enable access key based auth to the storage account as a work around as suggested in this similar post.

Root cause
The root of the issue was that I initially encountered the error because Unity Catalog was not configured on the workspace. After attaching the workspace to the Unity Catalog metastore, and setting up the storage credential/external location etc, I was attempting to validate that the new configuration was working by using the Rerun task function in the Data Factory Pipeline:

When running the task using this method, data factory used the existing job cluster definition which did not have Unity Catalog enabled:

Solution
To solve the issue, I changed the Databricks Linked Service configuration and set the Unity Catalog Access Mode to Assigned

I then ran the job in a new run - the notebook execution was successful. My sense is it was the execution of the pipeline as a new job after enabling Unity Catalog on the workspace, rather than the Unity Catalog Access Mode configuration, that fixed the issue.
